# Colossus Background Task

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, colossus

I am building an application using Tumblr's new Colossus framework (http://tumblr.github.io/colossus/). There is still limited documentation on it (and the fact that I'm still very new to Akka doesn't help), so I was wondering if someone could chime in on whether my approach is correct.

The application is simple and consists of two key components:

- A thin web service layer that will queue tasks into Redis
- A background worker which will poll the same Redis instance for available tasks and process them as they become available

I made a simple example to demonstrate that my concurrency model will work (and it does), which I posted below. However, I would like to make sure that there is not a more idiomatic way to do this.

```scala
import colossus.IOSystem
import colossus.protocols.http.Http
import colossus.protocols.http.HttpMethod.Get
import colossus.protocols.http.UrlParsing._
import colossus.service.{Callback, Service}
import colossus.task.Task

object QueueProcessor {
  implicit val io = IOSystem()   // Create separate IOSystem for worker

  Task { ctx =>
    while(true) {
      // Below code is for testing purposes only. This is where the Redis loop will live, and will use a blocking call to get the next available task
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      println("task iteration")
    }
  }

  def ping = println("starting")  // Method to launch this processor
}


object Main extends App {
  implicit val io = IOSystem()  // Primary IOSystem for the web service

  QueueProcessor.ping  // Launch worker

  Service.serve[Http]("app", 8080) { ctx =>
    ctx.handle { conn =>
      conn.become {
        case req@Get on Root => Callback.successful(req.ok("Here"))
        // The methods to add tasks to the queue will live here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tested the above model and it works. The background loop continues running while the service happily accepts requests. But, I think that there might be a better way to do this with workers (nothing found in documentation), or perhaps Akka Streams?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with something that seems semi-idiomatic to me. However, new answers & feedback are still welcomed!

```scala
class Processor extends Actor {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  override def receive = {
    case "start" => self ! "next"
    case "next" => {
      Future {
        blocking {
          // Blocking call here to wait on Redis (BRPOP/BLPOP)

          self ! "next"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  implicit val io = IOSystem()

  val processor = io.actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Processor])
  processor ! "start"

  Service.serve[Http]("app", 8080) { ctx =>
    ctx.handle { conn =>
      conn.become {
        // Queue here
        case req@Get on Root => Callback.successful(req.ok("Here\n"))
      }
    }
  }
}
```